# Creating std subrange from boost archive iterators

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, std-ranges, type-constraints

I'm using Boost's archive iterators to encode and decode base64, I can create a pair of iterators that represent an encoded string and use them to constuct types like `std::string` no problem. The problem arises when I try to use these iterators to construct a `std::ranges::subrange`, the compiler tells me that the iterators do not satisfy the constraints for the class template.

```
using namespace boost::archive::iterators;
using encode = base64_from_binary<transform_width<std::string::iterator, 6, 8>>;

std::string s("Hello World!");

encode b(s.begin());
encode e(s.end());

// works no problem, prints base64 encoded text
std::string output_string(b, e);
std::cout << output_string << std::endl;

// fails as constraints were not satisfied for the template
std::ranges::subrange<encode> output_range(b, e);
```

I've tried specifying the templates arguments a number of ways, but always get the following error.
error C7602: 'std::ranges::subrange': the associated constraints are not satisfied.

The full errror message being

```
====================[ Build | BASE64TEST | Debug ]==============================
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\untitled7\cmake-build-debug --target BASE64TEST -j 10
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\BASE64TEST.dir\base64.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/BASE64TEST.dir/base64.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP  -IC:\Users\me\CLionProjects\untitled7 -I"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_82_0" /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -std:c++latest -MDd -Zi /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\BASE64TEST.dir\base64.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\BASE64TEST.dir\ /FS -c C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\untitled7\base64.cpp
C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\untitled7\base64.cpp(64): error C7602: 'std::ranges::subrange': the associated constraints are not satisfied
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xutility(3370): note: see declaration of 'std::ranges::subrange'
C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\untitled7\base64.cpp(64): error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'std::ranges::subrange'
C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\untitled7\base64.cpp(64): error C2783: 'std::ranges::subrange<_It,_Se,_Ki> std::ranges::subrange(std::true_type,_Rng &&)': could not deduce template argument for '_It'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xutility(3383): note: see declaration of 'std::ranges::subrange'
C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\untitled7\base64.cpp(64): error C2780: 'std::ranges::subrange<_It,_Se,_Ki> std::ranges::subrange(std::ranges::subrange<_It,_Se,_Ki>)': expects 1 arguments - 2 provided
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xutility(3370): note: see declaration of 'std::ranges::subrange'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint that isn't satisfied seems to be `std::weakly_incrementable`, specifically the requirement

```
{ ++i } -> std::same_as<I&>;
```

This is because `base64_from_binary` inherits `operator++` from `boost::iterators::transform_iterator`, and doesn't implement it's own.

This means `base64_from_binary` isn't going to interoperate with anything constrained on C++20 iterator constraints, but will interoperate with things specified in earlier standards.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can make a subrange from a transfrom iterator, but then can't make a string from that range.
The following code does manage to compile.

    
    `auto b = boost::make_transform_iterator(s.begin(), swap);`
    `auto e = boost::make_transform_iterator(s.end(), swap);`
    
    `std::ranges::subrange range(b, e);`

Comment: @Indigo yes, this is specific to how `base64_from_binary` is defined